# The bottom strip of the view in iOS Storyboard is not displayed on the iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface, uistoryboard

The bottom strip of my view in storyboard is not displaying on the iPad.  I am not sure if it is not being drawn or if the view on Storyboard is too big.

- UILabel is not hidden
- Changing color of text has no effect
- Everything else appears without issue
- In the Attributes Inspector, I have size set to iPad Full Screen

### Bottom Strip in Storyboard:

[image: Bottom Strip in Storyboard]

### Bottom Strip on Simulator:

[image: Bottom Strip on Simulator]

Comment: Is the storyboard scene set up for an iPhone 5 and you're running on 4S size display?

Comment: I am running it on iPad (Retina), but I am not sure how to check how my Storyboard Scene is set up

Comment: Hm, are you using a navigation bar or a tab bar that is not being accounted for?

Comment: @Stakenborg that is it! I was not accounting for my nav bar. Would you mind putting that as an answer so others can find it?

Comment: Sure, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely either a tab bar or a navigation bar that is not being accounted for. These can be simulated on IB via the attributes pane on the view controller you're working with.